# Detect empty lists in R

Tags: r, list, string-length

I am calculating some values which are stored in a list and the list is appended to an already existing list, called `results`. In some cases the calculation returns `TRUE`. In that case I want to remove the element that returned `TRUE` from the list:

```
my_list
$`0`
[1] TRUE

$`1`
[1] TRUE


my_list = lapply(list(my_list), function(x){Filter(Negate(isTRUE), x)})
> my_list
[[1]]
named list()
```

This return an empty list. Now I want to check:

- if the list is empty - do nothing
- if the list is not empty append it to results

The problem is that when I check

```
length(my_list) >0
[1] TRUE
```

How can I detect if a list is empty?

Comment: In this case, what is the expected output.  Do you need `my_list[lengths(my_list) > 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to get the logical output for each `list` element

```
my_list[lengths(my_list) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Data
my_list <- list('0'=T,'1'=T)
my_list = lapply(list(my_list), function(x){Filter(Negate(isTRUE), x)})
#Code
lapply(my_list, function(x) length(x)>0)
```

Output:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) length(x)>0)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `Filter` approach can work for you

```
> Filter(length, my_list)
list()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Empty" may not always be what one expects. `rlang` `is_empty` function may help.

`length(list()) > 0` gives `FALSE`,

`length(list(NA)) > 0` gives `TRUE`,

yet  `length(list(NULL)) > 0` gives `FALSE`.

```
my_list <- list(NA,NULL,list(1,2), function(x){length(x)}, list(), NaN)
lapply(my_list, rlang::is_empty)
```

output

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE
[[2]]
[1] TRUE
[[3]]
[1] FALSE
[[4]]
[1] FALSE
[[5]]
[1] TRUE
[[6]]
[1] FALSE
```